# How to merge two arrays into one array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays that looks like this:

```
  0 => string '2014-02-14' (length=10)
  1 => string '2014-03-14' (length=10)
  2 => string '2014-04-14' (length=10)
  3 => string '2014-05-14' (length=10)
  4 => string '2014-06-16' (length=10)
  5 => string '2014-07-14' (length=10)
```

and the other:

```
  0 => string '2014-01-30' (length=10)
  1 => string '2014-02-27' (length=10)
  2 => string '2014-03-31' (length=10)
  3 => string '2014-04-30' (length=10)
  4 => string '2014-05-29' (length=10)
  5 => string '2014-06-30' (length=10)
```

what i want to do is to merge this two arrays in a specific way so i can use it forward to CSV, so i need to be like this:

```
  0 => string '2014-02-14,2014-02-14'
```

so it should be `firstarray_value`,`secondarray_value` for the new array, is there anyway to manipulate this two arrays to be come one array in that for described above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just try with:

```
$array1 = array( /* your data */ );
$array2 = array( /* your data */ );
$output = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($array1); ++$i) {
  $output[] = $array1[$i] . ',' . $array2[$i];
}
```

To use it with `fputcsv`:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array1); ++$i) {
  $output[] = array($array1[$i], $array2[$i]);
}

foreach ($output as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}
```

Edit:

You can merge those arrays quicker with:

```
$output = array_map(null, $array1, $array2);
```

and then also:

```
foreach ($output as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}
```

Comment: hsz thank you for your answer, although when i make var_dump of the `$output` it gives me a correct format, if i do : `$fp = fopen('files.csv', 'w');

foreach ($outputas $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);` the CSV file is empty, do you know if it's from the format or ... ? Thanks!

Comment: @Liza To use it with `fputcsv` you have to pass as a second argument an array. Look at my edit.

Comment: @Liza In my last edit I show you a quicker way to merge your arrays. It's quite tricky :)

Comment: Thank you for that! :) tiny question: if i want to insert a header for this CSV file like `first_date,second_date` how is it possible? Thanks

Comment: Do `fputcsv($fp, array('first_date','second_date'));` before loop

Answer (score 1):

```
$array3 = array();
foreach($array1 as $key=>$val){
    $array3[] = $val.",".$array2[$key];
}
print_r($array3);
```

Comment: @OliverBS your edit was not necessary, both of `$val.",".$array2[$key]` and `"$val,$array2[$key]"` are correct. I dont understand why you must down vote this answer!!!!